# Tabbing environment: How to line break?

Tags: line-breaking, tabbing

I'm desperately trying to get a linebreak in a CV at the end of my dissertation. When I do this:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{4.5cm}\=\kill
09/2004 -- 11/2010 \> \textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt} \+ \\ Blablabla
\end{tabbing}
```

It works perfectly.

When I add another line:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{4.5cm}\=\kill
09/2004 -- 11/2010 \> \textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt} \+ \\ Blablabla
09/2004 -- 11/2010 \> \textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt} \+ \\ Blablabla
\end{tabbing}
```

I get `! LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position.`

What the hell am I doing wrong? I don't get it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\+` *"causes the left margin of subsequent lines to be indented one tab stop to the right"* (Lamport, *LaTeX: A document preparation system*, p. 202), so your second "Study of Biology" entry is placed at the third tab stop -- which doesn't exist, which in turn throws an error. The error may be avoided by adding `\-` (the complement to `\+`) plus a line break after the first "Blablabla".

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{4.5cm}\=\kill
09/2004 -- 11/2010 \> \textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt} \+ \\ Blablabla \- \\
09/2004 -- 11/2010 \> \textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt} \+ \\ Blablabla
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

Another option is to do without `\+` and `\-` and simply add `\>` at the start of lines 2 and 4.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{4.5cm}\=\kill
09/2004 -- 11/2010 \> \textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt} \\ 
\> Blablabla \\
09/2004 -- 11/2010 \> \textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt} \\ 
\> Blablabla
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first `Blablabla` together with the start of the next input line moves beyond the first tab position, so the `\>` in the second line looks for another tab position.  But there is none.

What is the point of those `Blablabla` sequences?  They don't belong in the line they appear in.

Comment: Exchange the Blablablas for something like "Emphasis on Microbiology, Genetics and Biochemistry", some additional information which should appear below `\textbf{Study of Biology at TU Darmstadt}`