# Latex tabbing: Undefined tab position

Tags: errors, tabbing

I am getting error"! LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position." for the following snippet of latex code.

```
\begin{tabbing}
\> \>$n$ = Some data\\
\> \>$B$ = Another Statement\\
\> \>$N$ = Yet another statement\\
\end{tabbing}
```

I looked at the related post: [Tabbing environment: How to line break?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56793/tabbing-environment-how-to-line-break), but I cannot figure out the reason for error. Can someone suggest how to fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set tab positions first (either in your first line or in a `\kill`ed line):

First line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\= \= $n$ = Some data\\
\> \> $B$ = Another Statement\\
\> \> $N$ = Yet another statement
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

`\kill`ed line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2em} \= \hspace{3em} \= $N$ = Yet another statement \= \kill
\> \> $n$ = Some data \> (1) \\
\> \> $B$ = Another Statement \> (2) \\
\> \> $N$ = Yet another statement \> (3)
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```