# "Undefined tab position" when trying to generate PDF with Doxygen and pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex

I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70222/latex-tabbing-undefined-tab-position) but it doesn't help me.

I know nothing about TEX, all I care is to extract Doxygen documentation from a C project in a PDF.

For that, the DoxyWizard wants me to generate TEX files ready for hyperlinked PDFs, then I use the pdflatex tool (I actually run an autogenerated `make.bat` to do that) and it generates me a PDF.

Problem is that while running the pdflatex tool some **"LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position"** messages appear which determine a lot of linking errors in the resulting PDF.

Where should I be looking for the cause of these errors?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: You presumably have a `tabbing` environment and commands such as `\>` to move to the next tab position without defining that position. But without an example, hard to say.

Comment: I wouldn't know what to show you really... I'm running Doxygen GUI frontend and it generates a folder filled mostly with .TEX files and a `make.bat` along a makefile. I just run the bat file and the console stops at times giving me errors. The generated PDF is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are using `tabbing` and have moved to  a tab beyond the last defined tab on the line.

```
! LaTeX Error: Undefined tab position.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7   x\> y \>
               z
?
```

The above error shows (via the position of the line break) that the second tab `\>` is not defined. The reason being that there is only one `\=` setting tab stops in the first line of this test file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
  aaaaa\= bbbb\\
  x\> y \> z
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```